# making a query from several categories

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a blog, and I want to make a sql query, to provide all the blogs that belong to several arbitrary categories.

I thought I could do it with

```
SELECT * FROM `blog` WHERE `blog_category_id` IN($categories) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

But then I forgot that the categories come from another table, and now I am really struggling to work this out.

So I am trying to return all the info from the rows in the blog table, and find the blogs from the blogs_to_cats table

blogs_to_cats table contains blog_id and blog_category_id.

So what I have is an array of blog_category_id's, from here I want to generate the query.

What is the correct sql query to accomplish something like this, some sort of array table join?

Comment: How can we tell if you didn't post table schemas for both tables and sample data?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT blog.*
FROM blog b
INNER JOIN blog_to_cat bc ON b.id = bc.blog_id
WHERE bc.blog_category_id IN $categories
```